# Не подгружаются картинки

Tags: reactjs, redux

Подскажите пожалуйста почему не подгружаются картинки? Вроде все верно подключил...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

cartReducer.js

```
    import Item1 from "../images/item1.jpg";
import Item2 from "../images/item2.jpg";
import Item3 from "../images/item3.jpg";
import Item4 from "../images/item4.jpg";
import Item5 from "../images/salat-ceszar.jpg";
import Item6 from "../images/salat-s-krabovumi-palochkami.jpg";
import Item7 from "../images/salat-shyba.jpg";
import Item8 from "../images/salat-stolichny.jpg";
import Item9 from "../images/coffe-black.jpg";
import Item10 from "../images/black-tea.jpg";
import Item11 from "../images/сacao.jpg";
import Item12 from "../images/item12.jpg";
import Item13 from "../images/fanta.jpg";
import Item14 from "../images/green-tea.jpg";
import Item15 from "../images/sprite.jpg";

const initState = {
  items: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Фирменная",
      category: "pizza",
      price: 60,
      description: "Курица, грибы, сыр, томатный соус",
      img: { Item1 },
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Курица с грибами",
      category: "pizza",
      price: 50,
      description: "Курица, грибы, томатный соус",
      img: { Item2 },
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Мясная",
      category: "pizza",
      price: 70,
      description: "Ветчина, сыр, помидор, чеснок, соус, майонез",
      img: { Item3 },
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "Курица с ветчиной",
      category: "pizza",
      price: 50,
      description: "Ветчина, соус, сыр, майонез",
      img: { Item4 },
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "Цезарь",
      category: "salat",
      price: 35,
      description: "Куриное филе, листья салата, сухарики, майонез, чеснок",
      img: { Item5 },
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: "С крабовыми палочками",
      category: "salat",
      price: 30,
      description: "Крабовые палочки, яйца, кукуруза, огурец, майонез",
      img: { Item6 },
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      name: "Селедка под шубой",
      category: "salat",
      price: 29,
      description: "Селедка, свекла, картошка, майонез",
      img: { Item7 },
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: "Столичный",
      category: "salat",
      price: 32,
      description: "Курица, горошек, огурцы, капуста, картошка, майонез",
      img: { Item8 },
    },
    {
      id: 9,
      name: "Черный кофе",
      category: "drink",
      price: 20,
      description: "",
      img: { Item9 },
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      name: "Черный чай",
      category: "drink",
      price: 20,
      description: "",
      img: { Item10 },
    },
    {
      id: 11,
      name: "Какао",
      category: "drink",
      price: 20,
      description: "",
      img: { Item11 },
    },
    {
      id: 12,
      name: "Кола",
      category: "drink",
      price: 20,
      description: "",
      img: { Item12 },
    },
    {
      id: 13,
      name: "Фанта",
      category: "drink",
      price: 20,
      description: "",
      img: { Item13 },
    },
    {
      id: 14,
      name: "Зеленый чай",
      category: "drink",
      price: 20,
      description: "",
      img: { Item14 },
    },
    {
      id: 15,
      name: "Спрайт",
      category: "drink",
      price: 20,
      description: "",
      img: { Item15 },
    },
  ],
  addedItems: [],
  total: 0,
};

const cartReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  return state;
};
export default cartReducer;
```

и вот куда подключаю

Pizza.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Card, Button, CardColumns } from "react-bootstrap";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Pizza extends Component {
  render() {
    let itemList = this.props.items.map((item) => {
      return (
        <Card className="text-center" border="primary" key={item.id}>
          <Card.Img variant="top" src={item.img} />
          <Card.Body>
            <Card.Title>{item.name}</Card.Title>
            <Card.Subtitle>{item.price}</Card.Subtitle>
            <Card.Text>{item.description}</Card.Text>
            <Button variant="primary">В корзину</Button>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      );
    });
    return <CardColumns className="m-3">{itemList}</CardColumns>;
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    items: state.items,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Pizza);
```

Comment: Картинка входит в состав Card

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо убрать скобки:

```
img: { Item1 }
```

должно быть: `img: Item1`,  в массиве.
Со скобками получается что `item.img` равен объекту в котором свойство Item1 равно строке с адресом картинки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]